# Passing data between two view controllers via a protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

How to declare and implement a protocol that will return a view's property?
E.g. I have an view called mainView and I want it to be able to return an array when another view, customView for example, asks for it.
What I'm doing is that I'm declaring a protocol in the mainView implementation file (with a returnTheArray function) and set the customView to adopt this protocol, but I'm stuck at this point. What should I do to get this working correctly? Or there is a more effective/easy/correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. From an UIViewController to a UITableViewController

Comment: I don't see why you need a protocol, if the viewcontrollers have references to each other you can just add a method.

Comment: meggar is correct. You would not necessarily need a protocol. Especially as it is just betwenn these two classes. However, I understood your question rather like "how do I implement a protocol". Thats why I just posted the skeleton example of how to implement a protocol. In your specific case I would not bother defining a protocol. If it is really a proerty then define it in the interface, add the (at)property and (at)synthesize statements and use the synthesized getter method to fetch it. That would be getTheArray if the name is theArray. That's what (at)synthesize does for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol as such is only a declaration of the function/method name, parameters and return values. As a protocol to me is only reasonalbe when it is fulfilled by a number of classes, I personally prefer to declare it in an individual header protocolName.h.

Every class that conforms to the protocol needs to implement the method(s). For my undertanding it is as simple as that.

*AClass.h*

@itnerface AClass:NSObject {
// some properties
}
// @property statements
@end

*AClass.m*

```
#include "BClass.h"

@implementation AClass

//@synthesize statements;

- (void) aFunctionFetchingTheArray {

  BClass *bClass = [[BClass alloc] initWithSomething:kParameter];

  NSArray *anArray = [bClass returnTheArray];

  //Do something with it

}

@end
```

*MyProtocol.h*

```
@protocol MyProtocol 

- (NSArray *) returnTheArray;

@end
```

*BClass.h*

```
#include "MyProtocol.h"

@interface BClass <MyProtocol> {
// some properties in interface
}
// some @property
// some methods
@end
```

*BClass.m*

```
#include "BClass.h"  //No need to include MyProtocol.h here too, in this case

- (NSArray *) returnTheArray {
return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", [NSNumber numberWithtInt:1], [UIColor clearColor], somethingElse, evenMore, nil];
}

// more methods

@end
```

Please correct my if I missed or misspelled something of importance.

Comment: It is worth mentioning the name convention for delegate methods (the methods in the protocol which BClass conforms to via <MyProtocol>). Have a look at this: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/method-names-in-objective-c.html

Comment: What do you mean initWithSomething? How do I tell the AClass that BClass *bClass is the controller BClass, not just some empty controller?

Comment: In General you should call the init mehtod. Just in case you want to pass some data to your new object in order to initialze it, it may be a good idea to do that in your init-method and pass the parameters and name the method accordingly. If you want to init your Object with a train ticket then you could call it initWithTrainTicket. That's all. :) (call [super init| within that method)